# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined React/Redux/Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

When calling the action in question (postRequest), it returns this data undefined error, the action however is successful & refreshing clears the error.

error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined:
        payload: err.response.data
```

Front-end:

```
 handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.postRequest({ body: this.state.body });
  };
```

```
export const postRequest = newRequest => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
  axios
    .post('/request', newRequest)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_REQUEST,
        payload: res.data
      });
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
};
```

Back-end:

```
exports.newRequest = (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.body.trim() === "") {
    return res.status(400).json({ body: "Body must not be empty" });
  }

  db.collection("requests")
    .where("userHandle", "==", req.user.handle)
    .where("status", "==", "awaiting")
    .limit(1)
    .get()
    .then(data => {
      if (!data.empty) {
        return res
          .status(403)
          .json({ general: `Only 1 outstanding request at a time` });
      }
      return db
        .collection("requests")
        .add(newRequest)
        .then(doc => {
          const resRequest = newRequest;
          resRequest.requestId = doc.id;
          res.json({ resRequest });
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: `sum ting wong` });
      console.error(err);
    });
};
```

I can't figure out why - if there is no error being caught - why the err.response.data payload being undefined would be a problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** Updated front-end w/ if statement per Axios docs, however now no error is thrown it just continues to load, still actions goes through & refreshing fixes.

```
 .catch(err => {
      if (err.response) {
            dispatch({
          type: SET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        });
          }
    });
```

Comment: `err.response.data` is not undefined, it's `err.response` that is undefined

Comment: See https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors. Note how the example checks for the _truthiness_ of `error.response`

Comment: Ok thanks, I implemented that & now great no error is thrown, but it's stuck loading -I updated the main post.

Comment: @ExoPlanet3000 where's the rest of your error checking? Ie `else if (error.request) { ... } else { ... }`. The example makes it pretty clear what you should be checking

Comment: I tried it & it seemed ineffective - Just tried again & now it works flawlessly. Case closed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

It’s throwing an error because you need to `JSON.parse()` the response before you access the data property.

```
axios
    .post('/request', newRequest)
    // add this
    .then(resp => JSON.parse(resp))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: POST_REQUEST,
        payload: res.data
      });
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      });
    });
```

Without parsing the JSON your code can't access the data property so it throws an error.

And once it throws there is no response property on the error object. 
 Remove that line, add a console.log, and you will see it throw the error.

Comment: Axios automatically transforms JSON responses into JS objects. Your example would also fail because [`resp` is an object already](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) and not a string

Comment: Oh whoops mid read and thought it was fetch. Where is resp already a variable though?

Comment: In your answer... `.then(resp => JSON.parse(resp))`. That won't work because Axios resolves the promise with a _Response Schema_ object. Also, if this was using `fetch`, you still would not resolve the JSON data this way. You would use `fetch(...).then(res => res.json())`

Comment: I get that about axios, I thought it was fetch. But that makes sense about fetch, I knew you needed to turn it into json but couldn’t remember how. Thanks for the correction